# Inkscape - background for single components appearing

Tags: inkscape

Even though the drawing looks perfectly fine on Inkspace:

[image]

When I export it to .pdf it becomes like this:

[image]

What could be the reason? Is there any way to change it?

Comment: are those components vector objects? Can you add more info?

Comment: Are there any layers in the Inkscape SVG? It looks as though you have additional semi-transparent shapes in a separate layer that might be hidden in Inkscape. Check your layers with `Shift+Ctrl+L` (and the 'eye' icon). When you export a PDF the invisible objects get merged and thus the overlapping shapes start to appear. Just a guess, hard to tell without the original file...

Comment: Is there a way for me to add the file on here?

Comment: I think you can only upload images directly (via Imgur). You can post a link to a shared file on DropBox, GoogleDrive etc., though. Simply add `[<description>](<url>)` to your question.